# Yii2 Facebook oauth - Integrity constraint violation: 1048 - Column'email' cannot be null

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, yii2

I'm using Yii2 framework.

To log into my website, users can do it with the traditional way and with the Facebook login.

However, when user is already created using the traditional way, if they try to log in again but this time with the facebook button, the "integrity constraint violation window" shows up.

The message displays:
**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity violation:1048 Column 'email' cannot be null. The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO 'user'('username','email','oauth_client','oauth_user_id','password_hash','status'.........**

CONTROLLER

```
class SignInController extends \yii\web\Controller

{

public function actions()
{
    return [
        'oauth' => [
            'class' => 'yii\authclient\AuthAction',
            'successCallback' => [$this, 'successOAuthCallback']
        ]
    ];
}


public function successOAuthCallback($client)
{
    $attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
    $user = User::find()->where([
        'oauth_client' => $client->getName(),
        'oauth_client_user_id' => ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'id')
    ])->one();
    if (!$user) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->scenario = 'oauth_create';
        /*echo '<pre>';   var_dump($attributes);exit;*/
        if ($client->getName() === 'facebook') {
            $user->username = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'id');
            $user->email = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'email'); 
        }
        if ($client->getName() === 'google') {
            $user->username = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'id');
            $user->email = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'emails.0.value');
        }
        $user->oauth_client = $client->getName();
        $user->oauth_client_user_id = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'id');
        $password = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(8);
        $user->setPassword($password);
        if ($user->save()) {
            $profileData = [];
            if ($client->getName() === 'facebook') {
                $profileData['firstname'] = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'first_name');
                $profileData['lastname'] = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'last_name');
            }
            if ($client->getName() === 'google') {
                $profileData['firstname'] = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'name.givenName');
                $profileData['lastname'] = ArrayHelper::getValue($attributes, 'name.familyName');
            }

            $user->afterSignup($profileData);
            $sentSuccess = Yii::$app->commandBus->handle(new SendEmailCommand([
                'view' => 'oauth_welcome',
                'params' => ['user'=>$user, 'password'=>$password],
                'subject' => Yii::t('frontend', '{app-name} | Tu nuevo usuario', ['app-name'=>Yii::$app->name]),
                'to' => $user->email
            ]));
            if ($sentSuccess) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash(
                    'alert',
                    [
                        'options'=>['class'=>'alert-success'],
                        'body'=>Yii::t('frontend', 'Welcome to {app-name}. Email with your login information was sent to your email.', [
                            'app-name'=>Yii::$app->name
                        ])
                    ]
                );
            }

        } else {
            // We already have a user with this email. Do what you want in such case
            if ($user->email && User::find()->where(['email'=>$user->email])->count()) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash(
                    'alert',
                    [
                        'options'=>['class'=>'alert-danger'],
                        'body'=>Yii::t('frontend', 'We already have a user with email {email}', [
                            'email'=>$user->email
                        ])
                    ]
                );
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash(
                    'alert',
                    [
                        'options'=>['class'=>'alert-danger'],
                        'body'=>Yii::t('frontend', 'Error while oauth process.')
                    ]
                );
            }

        };
    }
    if (Yii::$app->user->login($user, 3600 * 24 * 30)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new Exception('OAuth error');
    }
}
```

}

VIEW:

```
       <div>
               <?= yii\authclient\widgets\AuthChoice::widget([
                       'baseAuthUrl' => ['sign-in/oauth']
                ])?>
       </div>
```

Comment: Some Facebook users don't have emails associated, so you'll either have to ask for it, or adjust your application to handle a null email.

Comment: but the problem happens when you sign in the traditional way, and then with the email already registered you try to log in again but this time with the facebook button...

Comment: Yes, you'd have to provide a way to merge the accounts in that scenario.

Comment: I see, any sources or similar examples I could look at to implement in my project maybe? Thanks for your answers!